# Do redirect with a imported function in a called view

Tags: django, redirect, view

I have a Django App "A" with a view "view_A" where I execute a function:

```
from app_B.views import usercheck_B

def view_A(request):
  usercheck_B(request)
  return render(request)
```

And in my Django App "B" with a function "usercheck_B":

```
def usercheck_B(request):
  if not request.user.is_authenticated:
  redirect('view_B:login')
```

What I want is, that a directly redirect the client if he is not logged in in the called function. But that is not working. I only can return a Httpresponse to my first called view "view_A" a redirect to login.

My idea is to place the usercheck_B function in every view I have and redirect visitors. But I want to do this check also in special cases if for exapmple other parameters are not fitting.

Comment: You can use decorator instead, but what you do here already exists: that is the `@login_required` decorator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use decorator instead, but what you do here already exists: that is the [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator). Indeed, you can use:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def view_A(request):
    return render(request, 'some-template.html')
```

You can then set the login url in the [**`LOGIN_URL`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std-setting-LOGIN_URL):

```
# settings.py

from django.urls import reverse_lazy

# …

LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('view_B:login')
```

Comment: Thank, I will use this in this special case. But it not completly answering my question. Is a way existing where I can directly use "redirect( ..." or "render ..." in my imported function? Actually this is not working. "redirect( ..." or "render ..." only working in my first called view, in my imported function both are ignored.

Comment: @Booman989: you should *not* work with a view, but define a generator that wraps the view, so `usercheck_B` should be a decorator, not a view.